# Why does MVC Model binding require an index for collections?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Working on a project which required me to have many collections of related data on the same screen.

Example structure:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions {get; set;}
}

public class Question
{
    public string Text {get; set;}
    public string Answer {get; set}
    //Yes, in this example attachments are directly related to the question and not
    //a parent entity
    public IEnumerable<AttachmentInfo> Attachments {get; set;}
}

public class AttachmentInfo
{
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile {get; set;}
}
```

Using the above structure, you would end up with mark up similar to:

```
<input type="file" name="model.Questions[0].Attachments[0].Description" />
<input type="file" name="model.Questions[0].Attachments[0].PostedFile " />
```

To add another attachment, you would have to appropriately update the index like so:

```
<input type="text" name="model.Questions[0].Attachments[1].Description" />
<input type="file" name="model.Questions[0].Attachments[1].PostedFile " />
```

**Why does model binding work like this?**

I have looked for a specific reasons model binding works like this, but I can't find anything and can't think of scenarios where using a pattern like `model.Questions.Attachments.Description` wouldn't work properly. Model Binding to `IEnumerable<string>` already does a similar thing with simple types if they input elements have the same name assigned to them.

Comment: A decent explanation of MVC model binding in MSDN Magazine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: @async This is one of those instances that it says modeling binding works *like this*, but doesn't explain *why* it is like this.  I'm looking for the reason **why** it was decided collections of complex objects to be handled this way.  Good article though!

Comment: This kind of "why" questions can only be answered by the actual developers of the product, so these questions are often closed as subjective. However I can assume that without indices it is impossible to know to which instance of `Attachment` this `Description` field belongs, and when one instance of `Attachment` ends and another begins. You'd have to come up with a cumbersome convention for this, and it would be difficult to use and not flexible enough.